# AADSTS900561 Error in MSAL-Browser: Endpoint Only Accepts POST and OPTIONS Requests, Not GET – Unable to Retrieve Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, msal

I am trying to obtain a token in React using MSAL-Browser. With the following code, I encounter the following error when reaching "await this.publicClientApplication.loginPopup": "AADSTS900561: The endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request." Unfortunately, I couldn't find much information about this specific issue.

My problem is that I cannot receive a response in order to request a token. To request a token, I need, among other things, the "code." Does anyone have an idea of what might be causing this issue?

I have also attempted to set up an HTTP server to handle the response from MSAL. However, as soon as I log in, the URL "http://localhost:65192/#code=long_code_text_here&client_info=long_client_id_here&session_state=some_session_state_here&" is sent to the HTTP server, and with the "#" character, nothing is received. This prevents me from even processing the "code." As seen in the code, I have set the "response_mode" to "query" to use "?" instead of "#," but it appears that for MSAL-Browser, or specifically for loginPopup and loginRedirect, "response_mode = fragment" is static. Any ideas?

Edit: I do not have access to Azure AD, but I already have a Python solution running locally on my computer that obtains the token.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SelectionManager from "./SelectionManager";
import {config} from "./Config";
import {PublicClientApplication} from "@azure/msal-browser";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            user: {},
        };
        this.login = this.login.bind(this);
        // Initialize the MSAL application object
        this.publicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication({
            auth: {
                clientId: config.clientId,
                redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
                authority: config.authority,
                response_type: config.response_type,
                response_mode: "query"
            },
            cache: {
                cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
                storeAuthStateInCookie: false
            }
        });

        this.publicClientApplication.initialize();
        console.log("initialized");
    }

    async login() {
        console.log("logging in");
        try {
            console.log("try to open popup");

            const response = await this.publicClientApplication.loginPopup({
                scopes: config.scopes,
                prompt: "select_account"
            });

            console.log("popup may have been opened");
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
        }
        catch (err) {
            this.setState({
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: {},
                error: err
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.state.isAuthenticated ? <p>
                <SelectionManager/>
                </p>:
                    <p>
                        <button onClick={() => this.login()}> Login</button>
                    </p>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `response_mode` to "query". This is the correct setting for using the `response_type` "code". However, the `loginPopup` method does not support the "query" response mode.

Use the  `acquireTokenPopup`  method instead of the  `loginPopup`  method. The  `acquireTokenPopup`  method supports both the "query" and "fragment" response modes.

**Here is the code i have tried:**

```js
    // src/AuthButton.js
  
    import  React, { useEffect, useState } from  "react";
    import { PublicClientApplication } from  "@azure/msal-browser";
    import  msalConfig  from  "./msalConfig";
    
    const  AuthButton  = () => {
    const [publicClientApplication, setPublicClientApplication] =  useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
    const  initializeMsal  =  async () => {
    const  pca  =  new  PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    await  pca.initialize();
    setPublicClientApplication(pca); 
    }; 
    initializeMsal();   
    }, []);
    

    const  handleLogin  =  async () => {
    try {
    const  loginRequest  = {
    scopes: ["openid", "profile", "user.read"],
    };
    const  loginResponse  =  await  publicClientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest);
    console.log("Access token:", loginResponse.accessToken); 
    } 
    catch (error) {
    console.error("Authentication error:", error);
    }   
    };
    
    return (  
    <div>
    <button  onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
    );
    };

    export  default  AuthButton;
```

**Result**
[image]